# Dynamically adding textbox, dropdown with database filled values

Tags: php, jquery, json

I have this this set of textbox and dropdowns with autocomplete. Now i want to give an add button, when i click on add button, i shouuld get all these should repeat i mean 2 dropdown and 2 textboxes. I am able to do it with only textboxes, but for this i am not able to do it.

Here is my code

```
<script src="jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script>
$(function() {
    $( "#color" ).autocomplete({
        source: 'search.php'
    });
});
</script>
<script>
$(function() {
    $( "#size" ).autocomplete({
        source: 'search1.php'
    });
});
</script>
</head>

<body>
<div class="col-md-12">
<div class="row">
<div class="ui-widget">
    <label for="color">Item Color: </label>
    <input id="color" name="color" type="text">
</div>

<div class="ui-widget">
    <label for="size">Item Size: </label>
    <input id="size"name="size" type="text">
</div>

<div><input type="text" name="cost_price" /></div>
<div><input type="text" name="selling_price"  /></div>
</div>
</div>
```

search.php

```
<?php
    //database configuration
    $dbHost = 'localhost';
    $dbUsername = 'xxxx';
    $dbPassword = 'xxxx';
    $dbName = 'xxxx';


    $db = new mysqli($dbHost,$dbUsername,$dbPassword,$dbName);


    $searchTerm = $_GET['term'];


    $query = $db->query("SELECT * FROM leads WHERE company LIKE '".$searchTerm."%' ORDER BY company ASC");
    while ($row = $query->fetch_assoc()) {
        $data[] = $row['company'];
    }


    echo json_encode($data);
?>
```

It should happen like this
http://jsfiddle.net/niklasvh/BT2BE/

***** UPDATED ******
I am able to do it like this

```
echo '<form method="post" action="' . htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'],ENT_QUOTES,'UTF-8') . '" >';
    echo '<div>';
    echo '<input type="hidden" name="FormID" value="' . $_SESSION['FormID'] . '" />';
    echo '<br />'; ?>


<p> 
                    <input type="button" value="Add Attributes" onClick="addRow('dataTable')" /> 
                    <input type="button" value="Remove Attributes" onClick="deleteRow('dataTable')"  /> 
                    <p>(All acions apply only to entries with check marked check boxes only.)</p>
                </p>
 <table id="dataTable" class="selection">
                  <tbody>
                    <tr>
                      <p>
                        <td><input type="checkbox" required="required" name="chk[]" checked="checked" /></td>

                         <td>
                            <label for="Color">Select Color</label>
                            <select id="Color" name="Color[]" required="required">
                                <?php $sql = "SELECT * FROM itemcolor";
                                $result = DB_query($sql,$db);
                                while($myrow = DB_fetch_array($result))
                                { ?>
                                <option value="<?php echo $myrow['color_id']; ?>"><?php echo $myrow['color']; ?></option>
                                <?php } ?>
                            </select>
                         </td>
                          <td>
                            <label for="Size">Select Size</label>
                            <select id="Size" name="Size[]" required="required">
                                <?php $sql = "SELECT * FROM itemsizes";
                                $result = DB_query($sql,$db);

                                while($myrow = DB_fetch_array($result))
                                { ?>
                                <option value="<?php echo $myrow['size_id']; ?>"><?php echo $myrow['size']; ?></option>
                                <?php } ?>
                            </select>
                         </td>


                        <td>
                            <label>Cost Price</label>
                            <input type="text" required="required" name="Cost[]">
                         </td>
                         <td>
                            <label for="Sale">Selling Price</label>
                            <input type="text" required="required"  name="Selling_price[]">
                         </td>
                         <input type="hidden" name="stockid" value="<?php echo $stockID; ?>" />
                          <td>
                            <label for="Stock">Opening Stock</label>
                            <input type="text" required="required"  name="Opening_stock[]">
                         </td>


                            </p>
                    </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
                <div class="clear"></div>


<?php
    echo '<br /><div class="centre"><input type="submit" name="submit" value="' . _('Accept') . '" /><input type="submit" name="Cancel" value="' . _('Cancel') . '" /></div>';

    echo '</div>
          </form>'; 

if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
$stk = $_POST['stockid'];
foreach ($_POST['chk'] as $k) { 

$color = $_POST['Color'][$k];
$size = $_POST['Size'][$k];
$cost = $_POST['Cost'][$k];
$selling_price = $_POST['Selling_price'][$k];
$opening_stock = $_POST['Opening_stock'][$k];

$sql1 = "INSERT INTO itemarticles (stk_code, color, size, cost, selling_price, opening_stock) VALUES ('".$stk."', ".$color.", ".$size.", ".$cost.", ".$selling_price.", ".$opening_stock.")";   
$result = DB_query($sql1,$db);       
          if($result)
          {
          header("location:StockAttributes.php?Success=1");
          }
}          
 }
```

in Script

```
function addRow(tableID) {
    var table = document.getElementById(tableID);
    var rowCount = table.rows.length;
    if(rowCount < 30){                          // limit the user from creating fields more than your limits
        var row = table.insertRow(rowCount);
        var colCount = table.rows[0].cells.length;
        for(var i=0; i<colCount; i++) {
            var newcell = row.insertCell(i);
            newcell.innerHTML = table.rows[0].cells[i].innerHTML;
        }
    }else{
         alert("Maximum Attributes per Item is 30.");

    }
}

function deleteRow(tableID) {
    var table = document.getElementById(tableID);
    var rowCount = table.rows.length;
    for(var i=0; i<rowCount; i++) {
        var row = table.rows[i];
        var chkbox = row.cells[0].childNodes[0];
        if(null != chkbox && true == chkbox.checked) {
            if(rowCount <= 1) {                         // limit the user from removing all the fields
                alert("Cannot Remove all the Attributes.");
                break;
            }
            table.deleteRow(i);
            rowCount--;
            i--;
        }
    }
}
```

But i am not able to add the counter for each entry ... something like this `<input type="text" required="required"  name="Opening_stock[$counter]">`

I am not getting where to add the counter.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JQuery Autocomplete from Database](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25552994/jquery-autocomplete-from-database)

Comment: You might be repeating `id`s in your dynamic html. Use `data-*` attributes or `class` to make this work.

Comment: @theinarasu: My problem is different, i need to clone it.

Comment: @ShaunakD: Can you please refer me if any example are there...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10126414/3639582, http://stackoverflow.com/q/8612498/3639582

Comment: I have updated my question , i found the solution but not getting how to add counter for it, can someone please guide me in this?