# jquery autocomplete from database in spring boot

Tags: jquery, spring, spring-boot, autocomplete

I'm new to Spring boot,

I need to do autocomplete suggestion for my website and the data should be retrieved from database. I want to use JQuery autocomplete. here is my code but it doesn't work! The data is retrieved by using Spring boot in JSON form [have a look](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1FMT1G7hwX9EoszERydkY_f3aWAdDA-7W).

Please tell me if I'm missing something or I wrote something wrong or the source I gave is wrong, well here I did found [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25552994/jquery-autocomplete-from-database), it's on php but what matters is jQuery and [this one](https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/) too, and also [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hdqFm6lu_kg) in it he does on Spring boot and I did the same but it still don't work.

Here is my Controller:

```
@Controller
public class EmpController {
    @RequestMapping(value = "/autocomplete")
    @ResponseBody
    public List<String> autoName(){
        List<String> designation = dao.getDesignation();
        return designation;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/save",method = RequestMethod.POST)    
    public String save(@ModelAttribute("emp") Emp emp){
        dao.save(emp);
        return "redirect:/viewemp";
    }
```

Here is my jsp:

```
<body>
<form action="save" method="post">
Name: <input type="text" id="hint" name="hint" >
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="View">
</form>


<!-- JavaScript -->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/main.js"></script>
</body>
```

Here is my jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#hint").autocomplete({
      source: "/autocomplete",
      minLength: 1
  });
});
```

Please help..!!

Comment: Where are using `term` variable in your spring controller ?

Comment: I saw that autocomplete was not working so I did only the required part, you can refer to this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hdqFm6lu_kg), I'll do the narrowing stuff later once it starts suggesting..@SudhirOjha

Comment: I don't get it how it is possible duplicate, my question is on spring boot and jquery @SimonMartinelli

Comment: Have a look at $.getJSON in this answer

Comment: You should tell what doesn't work. Do you get any Java Script errors in the browser console?

Comment: No, I didn't got any javascript error. @SimonMartinelli

Comment: Have you tried to debug it in the browser?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code looks fine to me, Anyway

I too was stuck like you, so I did it from the Start..

you don't need to do it from the start, here is the code with autocomplete with narrowing too...

But remember if you are using jQuery to Autocomplete a text field, then you have to include these script and css links from [jQuery UI](https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/) in your html or jsp file.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

Controller:

```
@Controller
public class EmpController {
    @RequestMapping(value = "/autocomplete")
    @ResponseBody
    public List<String> autoName(@RequestParam(value = "term", required = false, defaultValue = "")String term){
        List<String> designation = dao.getDesignation(term);
        return designation;
    }

}
```

EmpDao:

```
@Service
public class EmpDao {

    @Autowired
    private EmpRepository repo;

    @Transactional
    public List<String> getDesignation(String term) {
        return repo.getDesignation(term);
    }
}
```

Repository:

```
public interface EmpRepository extends JpaRepository<Emp, Integer> {

@Modifying
    @Query(
            value = "select e.designation from emp69 e where e.designation LIKE %:term%",
            nativeQuery = true
    )
    List<String> getDesignation(String term);

}
```

JQuery:

```
$( function() {
    $( "#tags" ).autocomplete({
      source: "autocomplete",
      minLength: 3
    });
  } );
```

The `minLength: 3` will make field to start suggesting when input letter gets equal to 3

url of your autocomplete page will be: `http://localhost:8080/autocomplete?term=developer`

The `developer` in the url is your data saved as designation.

Hope this will help..

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
   $(function(){
     $.getJSON("http://example:8080/autocomplete", function(data) {
      $( "#hint" ).autocomplete({
         source: data    
           });
        });
    });
```